# Chart orientation in Achartengine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

How can I get Horizontal orientation in all graph ? I am  using the the demo chart file, and the CombinedTemperatureChart as my base.
I try this before return the intent:

```
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL); 
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCubicLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
                    renderer, 0.3f, "Average temperature");

    return intent;
```

And I also try this, before use the class.

```
    Intent lineIntent = graph.getIntent(this);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    startActivity(lineIntent);
```

In this case, I can see that the landscape is set up, before the chart is construct, but when the it comes ip, the orientation follows the device orientation. If I return to the list view, there, is the landscape orientation.

Some one could help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Orientation.VERTICAL`  instead of `Orientation.HORIZONTAL`

```
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

Actually `setOrientation()`

Sets the current orientation of the chart X axis.

Parameters:
orientation the chart orientation

Comment: Thanks for helping. 
It´s not the effect I would like. I´d like the chart only appear in landscape orientation, forcing the user to view in this position, where the chart is more visible.

Comment: then change ur manifest for that activity,add   android:screenOrientation="landscape"